# How to convert json object returned from browser to string in python lambda function

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Am a beginner to AWS, suppose I received a json object as following from client

```
[{'bid': 1, 'bodypart_name': 'Chest', 'image': 'image'}]
```

on which service of aws I would receive this object (am assuming it would get received in API gateway) and how should I convert that object to string in my lambda python function. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `str(json_object)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your client where they are sending this json request. If you are getting this on lambda you'll want to extract the values not turn the whole json object into a string. 
You can get the values like this:

```
json_obj = [{'bid': 1, 'bodypart_name': 'Chest', 'image': 'image'}]
for i in json_obj:
    print(i['bid'])
    print(i['bodypart_name'])
    print(i['image'])
```

The reason for the for loop is to capture multiple list objects. If you are sure you will only get 1 object inside list you can use `json_obj[0]['bid']` without loop.